# 500 Internal Server Error in WordPress. Tried everything

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I've got a pretty old and large WordPress website to fix and develop it. After I fixed some error, I got an `Internal Server Error 500` error globally to that subdomain (also for `wp-admin`, `wp-login`, `index.php`, etc).

Note: I don't have access to the `error.log` on the server.

The steps I've taken to try fix the issue:

- Firstly I checked for the `.htaccess` file, deleted it, manually recreated it with the WordPress defaults, but it didn't help.
- Secondly I increased the PHP limit with added a `php.ini` file, and also defined the limit in `wp-config.php`, but nothing changed.
- Then I deactivated all plugins (renamed the plugin directory), but still nothing.
- I updated the `wp-admin`, `wp-includes` directories, and some other core files from a newly installed WordPress.
- I realized that the directories and files permissions are wrong. I set the 644 (for files) and 755 (for directories) permissions. Still got the error.
- I modified the `home` and `site url` options in phpMyAdmin to the subdomain.
- After that I decided to reinstall the whole WordPress to fix the problem, and I started to downloading the `wp-content` to my computer (25 GB) when I found some `.php` files in the uploads and in the gallery. They were mostly some kind of backdoors. Fortunately Apache wasn't running on my machine.
- After all, I created an additional backup directory on the FTP server and moved the old WordPress site into that. I uploaded the newest WordPress to the original site location on the server, and set the `wp-config.php` file. But I sill got the `Internal Server Error 500` error.

Update: I've tried to setting up the `WP_DEBUG` with the following code:

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

It don't save the `debug.log` into the `wp-content` directory.
Also used this code in the `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  / <root>/public_html/PHP_errors.log
```

In conclusion, I guess the problem is in the MySQL database, but I hope I'm wrong. It's pretty large and no idea what could be the issue in that. Perhaps something in the `wp_options` table. I don't know.

I use WinSCP for FTP, and Notepad++ and Eclipse for editing.

Comment: `Tried everithing` yes, sure. Except reading error.log...

Comment: ^^ What he said and if for whatever you reason you can't access it... A try & catch in your Index.php should let you know what's up.

Comment: Check the error.log on your server and in that way you can solve your issues.

Comment: I don't have access to the log, but try & catch is a good idea. I'll try it.

Comment: Try setting the debug option to true in wp-config.php as define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

And also read the error logs - they are usually situated on /var/log/apache2 on ther server (or other place based on OS).

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error in my server and the problem is with the PHP version. Please make sure you have installed 5.4 version in your server. Other versions are not tested for WP and are causing problems. The next WP update may support 7.X versions.

> In short, find the PHP Version settings in the cPanel and change it to 5.4

Comment: I checked it. On cPanel there is nor info about the php version (I think we should move to another hosting provider :D), but I searched for it on their home page and found that the server default is php 5.3, in addition they support wordpress. By the way, there is more wp websites on our storage and all of it work fine.

Comment: Where have you rented the server?

Comment: Not me, but here is the link (but it's hungarian): http://webdigital.hu

Comment: Try GoDaddy or Namecheap. They are the industry standard best.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below solution, it works for me.

Select all the files from Root by using FTP (not Cpanel) and hit right click, you will see "File Permissions", Click on it and change Permission code to "0644", hit "ok". We're done.
Hope this help.